# Azure File Storage - Revert to prior snapshot

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I have an azure file storage share and I've taken a snapshot of it. It is clear to me that there is no functionality to directly restore an entire share from a snapshot. Is there a way to revert to the most recent snapshot, i.e. discard all post-snapshot changes?

Comment: Not understand your requirement clearly, could you provide more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `powershell` to access share snapshots from Windows.Follow the [step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orsq7.png) and copy the commands to powershell. It will connect automatically.

Then you right click the folder you want to revert and choose the **Properties** from the menu, then select **Previous Versions** to see the list of snapshots for this directory. And you can restore it here.You can refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#accessing-share-snapshots-from-windows).

If you still have questions, please let me know.